# Google Geocoding API always returns a lat long from centre of UK, no matter what search term we use

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

We've been using this API from quite some time. We could see addresses being returned out of the UK & hence changed the geocoding URL to restrict to UK only.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latLng=54,-2&address=gdfgsdgsd,GB

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latLng=54,-2&address=gdfgsdgsd,GB**&components=country:GB**

Please check the results for both of the above URL's. 
The first URL returns ZERO_RESULTS which is correct.
The second one always returns a lat long from centre of UK, no matter what search term we use.

You can also try replacing the value for 'address' to replicate the issue : 
452376452334,^$%^$%^$%,458352462354^$%^$%^

Comment: why are you including both the latLng (reverse geocoding only) and address (geocoding only) parameters?

Comment: [If you use a "real" (existing) address (like London), it works (returns a location other than the center of Great Britain)](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latLng=54,-2&address=London,GB&components=country:GB)

Comment: Removing latLng parameter or searching for a 'real' address doesn't resolve the issue I have. The postcode/location is entered in a text box by the user & then we invoke Google to georesolve. It was working fine until we introduced the parameter components=country:UK. But we had to introduce this so that non UK results aren't returned

Comment: You might want to indicate the actual problem you are trying to solve in your question and include that information.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Google Geocoding API about [Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering)

> A query containing a component filter will only return the geocoding
>   results that match the filter. If no matches are found, the geocoder
>   will return a result that matches the filter itself.

Request :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=someincomprehesibleaddress&components=administrative_area:TX|country:US&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
{
"results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Texas",
               "short_name" : "TX",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Texas, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.5007041,
                  "lng" : -93.5080389
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.8371638,
                  "lng" : -106.6456461
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 31.9685988,
               "lng" : -99.9018131
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.5015087,
                  "lng" : -93.5080389
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.8371638,
                  "lng" : -106.6456461
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJSTKCCzZwQIYRPN4IGI8c6xY",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**Component filtering will return a ZERO_RESULTS response only if you provide filters that exclude each other.**

Request :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area:TX|country:FR&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Comment: Yeah. But that doesn't solve the issue. I only have the address (postcode/location) which the user inputs. Based on this I need to georesolve to a UK location if it is a valid term. If not, I need to display an error message "Location not found". Now that it always returns results, I cannot do this. Only way I can think of now is to check if the result lat long is centre of UK [55.3780510, -3.4359730]. If yes, then consider it as 'Location not found'. If you have any other way round this, please let me know

Comment: As this is the inherent behavior of the Geocode service I doubt there is any solution to it. What you have suggested is one of the workarounds. The other workaround is to geocode without the component filter the way you were doing it earlier and then if a result is returned check the country in the address component. If it is outside UK or GB then you can display the error message "Location not found".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have found a way to resolve this.
The URL pattern I use now is : 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Leeds,UK|GB

The below URL now gives ZERO_RESULTs
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=gdfgsdgsd,UK|GB

Also as Joyson suggested, we could also check for the country returned back & display an error message.

Comment: Both your API requests are broken. As far as the API cares, "UK|GB" is the same as "UK GB" and that's not something that makes sense in an address. Also, using both latlng and address will make latlng ignored, which is why address=gdfgsdgsd (which is garbage) returns no results.

Comment: I've edited the second URL now. If you try the URL below, you get results from India http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=3123123,GB                                                                       But if you use the updated URL as given below, you'll get UK only results http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=3123123,UK|GB

Comment: Neither query restricts results to UK, they on bias, you need to use the components parameter in order to restrict results. Also, the correct country code for UK is actually GB (yeah) and putting both with the pipe is making for an ill-formed query.

Comment: You are right. This looks more appropriate. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=452376452334&components=country:GB